# How to access minikube machine from outside?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have a server running on ubuntu where I need to expose my app using kubernetes tools. I created a cluster using minikube with virtualbox machine and with the command kubectl expose deployment I was able tu expose my app... but only in my local network. It's mean that when I run minikube ip I receive a local ip.  My question is how can I access my minikube machine from outside ? 
I think the answer will be "port-forwarding".But how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SSH port forwarding to access your services from host machine in the following way:

```
ssh -R 30000:127.0.0.1:8001 $USER@192.168.0.20
```

In which `8001` is port on which your service is exposed, `192.168.0.20` is minikube IP.

Now you'll be able to access your application from your laptop pointing the browser to `http://192.168.0.20:30000`

Answer (score -1):

If you mean to access your machine from the internet, then the answer is yes "port-forwarding" and use the external ip address [https://www.whatismyip.com/]. The configurations go into your router settings. Check your router manual.